# How to avoid deleting diagrams from database when publishing in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssms, diagram

I've got a SQL Server 2014 database project in VS 2015. I've also created a couple of schema diagrams in SSMS (since VS doesn't have any schema diagramming that I'm aware of). It's early in the project's lifecycle and plenty of refactoring occurs. The SSMS diagrams are good at updating themselves in the face of change - which is really nice. I'd like to preserve the diagrams on (re)publish in the dev environment.

The problem is, to keep up with the refactorings, I'd need to delete things in the target database that are no longer in the project (or just recreate the target db in the dev environment)...but this will cause my diagrams to be blown away. I haven't figured out a clean way to avoid this and it's a kick in the shins to rebuild the diagrams. Has anybody figured out a reasonably clean way to incrementally publish while deleting project cruft yet preserving the diagrams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stage the Diagrams to a global temp table or a table in another database before you recreate the dev database.  You can do this by running something like this:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##TempTable') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE ##TempTable ;

SELECT  * 
INTO ##TempTable
FROM    sysdiagrams
```

Unfortunately you cannot successfully run this from a pre-deploy script if you Drop and recreate the dev database.  The pre-deploy script runs after the drop.  So I would look at creating a powershell script that publishes the dacpac, and before the dacpac deploy step execute the above statement to stage the diagrams.

After the dacpac is deployed, run something like this to recreate the diagrams:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.sysdiagrams (name, principal_id, version, definition)
SELECT name, principal_id, version, definition
FROM ##TempTable AS tt
```

Comment: Yeah - that's a good approach...will chew on it. I've noticed there are more objects than just sysdiagrams - there are at least some sprocs...and they appear to annotate the objects so that SSMS will put them in "System *xxx*" folders.

Comment: That's true. There are some things added on top of just those records.  I'll see if I can find some information on how to recreate those easily.

Comment: Well...if I just "back 'em up" into tempdb (per the first part of you answer), I can just hit the SSMS folder that creates the objects...and then I can run a slightly modified variant of the second part. That may be enough for now...but I'm gonna let this question stew a bit more - see if anybody else has some thoughts. Appreciate your effort!

Comment: Here is an article that includes scripts for creating the supporting objects: http://biinsight.com/how-to-install-database-diagram-support-programmatically/#more-602

Comment: Hmmm...that's cool...but I sure don't want to *own* those things. Was rooting around in `master` and `msdb` databases to see if there was a sproc that actually installed diagramming support...but to no avail so far.

Comment: Ooof! Stepped on my foot - so let me leave this one observation: if you redeploy between these two steps, *make sure* the SSMS session you have doesn't get forced closed...or it's "bye bye ##TempTable" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Anyone is still wanting to deal with diagrams should see this blog [Scripting an SSMS Diagram](https://rickbielawski.wordpress.com/2018/05/31/scripting-an-ssms-diagram/).  Basically it gives code that turns any diagram into an SSMS script.  Once scripted you can do anything you want including restore it to another system.

Keep in mind that diagrams only reference objects in the database.  They don't store any object data except their names.  So only objects that have the same type and name will appear in the diagram and others will give the 'will be removed from the diagram' warning.

It's a WordPress link so it should not change but if it does for some reason you can Google `Rick Bielawski Script Diagram` to find it wherever it is.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a lot of experience with visual studio database development, so this is more of an idea than an actual answer.

If you created a materialized (indexed) view of dbo.sysdiagrams and included it in the VS project would that prevent dbo.sysdiagrams from being blown away when you deployed?

```
create view test with schemabinding as select name, principal_id,diagram_id,version, definition from dbo.sysdiagrams 

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_test_diag 
    ON dbo.test(name, principal_id,diagram_id,version)
```

Comment: Thanks - I'd considered including source for the sysdiagrams artifacts directly into my project - but I really hate to "own" those objects, since some version of the tooling is free to change the implementation at some point in the future. What I'm really looking for is an API to capture and reconstitute the diagrams. Unfortunately, I've not found such an API...and so I have to wing it. I'm afraid creating the index wouldn't retain all the artifacts (there are procs and extended properties involved as well). I'm sure it would also cause the publish to break, too.

Comment: Did you see this:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15080/Script-SQL-Server-diagrams-to-a-file  ?   Seems like they are trying to solve the same problem you are.  It's similar to what Clay was recommending, but is wrapped up nicely.  Although it is T-SQL and not an API.

Comment: Interesting - A little different than what I'm trying to get to, but pretty good. between this and what @db_brad answered, I think I've hatched a solution.